# Grabbing data from a website with cURL after logging in?

Tags: php, curl

What I am trying to do is login to a website and then go and grab data from a table since they do not have an export feature. So far I've managed to login and it shows me the user homepage. However I need to navigate to a different page or somehow grab that page while still being logged in with curl.

My code so far:

```
$username="email"; 
$password="password"; 
$url="https://jiltapp.com/sessions"; 
$cookie="cookie.txt";
$url2 = "https://jiltapp.com/shops/shopname/orders";

$postdata = "email=".$username."&password=".$password; 

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); 

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
$result = curl_exec ($ch); 

echo $result;  
curl_close($ch);
```

As I mentioned i get access to the main user page, but I need to grab the contents of the $url2 variable, not $url. How can I accomplish something like that?

Thank you!

Comment: You are only doing one curl. How can you possibly be expecting to get information from a second page?

Comment: I am not expecting it, I don't know how to do it lol

Answer (score 7):

Once logged in, make a second request for the page that contains the data you are after.

For subsequent requets, you must set the option `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` which points to the same file as `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR`.  cURL will read cookies from this file and send them with the request.

```
$username="email"; 
$password="password"; 
$url="https://jiltapp.com/sessions"; 
$cookie="cookie.txt";
$url2 = "https://jiltapp.com/shops/shopname/orders";

$postdata = "email=".$username."&password=".$password; 

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);  // <-- add this line
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); 

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
$result = curl_exec ($ch); 

echo $result;  

// make second request

$url = 'page you want to get data from';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: @drew i had similar issue pls help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29875871/php-curl-post-data-to-get-value-form-referred-url