# php curl post data to get value form referred url

Tags: php, session, curl, cookies, libcurl

I want to send post data to a page to get value. The problem is that I want to get data form `abc.com`. And `abc.com` opens only if user comes to `abc.com` from `abc.com/previous url`.

Maybe it is is doing some session or cookies to authenticate. I have no idea.

What I want to do is get data from abc.com. Is there any way via curl to do it?

My php code:

When you run the code it says `url has be moved` as for this url you need to come from old refer url then it works in browser

```php
$SearchBy = "2";
$AttorneySearchMode="Name";
$LastName= "Smith";
$FirstName= "William";
$CaseStatusType= "0";
$SortBy= "fileddate";


echo $url = 'https://www.clarkcountycourts.us/Anonymous/Search.aspx?ID=400&NodeID=101%2c103%2c104%2c105%2c500%2c600%2c601%2c602%2c603%2c604%2c605%2c606%2c607%2c608%2c609%2c610%2c611%2c612%2c613%2c614%2c615%2c616%2c617%2c618%2c619%2c699%2c700%2c701%2c702%2c703%2c704%2c705%2c706%2c707%2c708%2c709%2c710%2c711%2c712%2c713%2c714%2c715%2c716%2c717%2c718%2c719%2c720%2c721%2c722%2c723%2c724%2c725%2c726%2c727%2c728%2c729%2c730%2c731%2c797%2c798&NodeDesc=All+Courts';

//set POST variables
$fields = array(
    'SearchBy' => urlencode($SearchBy),
    'AttorneySearchMode' => urlencode($AttorneySearchMode),
    'LastName' => urlencode($LastName),
    'FirstName' => urlencode($FirstName),
    'CaseStatusType' => urlencode($CaseStatusType),
    'SortBy' => urlencode($SortBy),
);
$fields_string = "";
foreach ($fields as $key=>$value) {
    $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&';
}
rtrim($fields_string, '&');
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a starting point with some minor additions.

I found 3 issues that prevented me from requesting the page on their server:

1. Need to enable cookies in cURL and fetch one page before posting
2. Needed to disable SSL checks (`CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER`, `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST`)
3. Some necessary form fields are missing from the request

In the example below I first fetch the main search page, and then re-use the same cURL handle to post the form.  Note this is incomplete, you will need to write code to populate the remaining form fields.

```
// first fetch search page to set cookies
$url = 'https://www.clarkcountycourts.us/Anonymous/Search.aspx?ID=400&NodeID=101%2c103%2c104%2c105%2c500%2c600%2c601%2c602%2c603%2c604%2c605%2c606%2c607%2c608%2c609%2c610%2c611%2c612%2c613%2c614%2c615%2c616%2c617%2c618%2c619%2c699%2c700%2c701%2c702%2c703%2c704%2c705%2c706%2c707%2c708%2c709%2c710%2c711%2c712%2c713%2c714%2c715%2c716%2c717%2c718%2c719%2c720%2c721%2c722%2c723%2c724%2c725%2c726%2c727%2c728%2c729%2c730%2c731%2c797%2c798&NodeDesc=All+Courts';

$ch = curl_init();

// needed to disable SSL checks for this site
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);

// enable cookie handling (they aren't saved after cURL is closed)
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '');

// debugging
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_STDERR, fopen('php://output', 'w'));

// helpful options
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);

// set first URL
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);

// execute first request to establish cookies & referer    
$data = curl_exec($ch);

// TODO: extract hidden form fields/values from form 
$fields_string = '...';

// now make second request
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($result);
```

See some of my other answers [linked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307744/how-to-login-in-with-curl-and-ssl-and-cookies/10307956#10307956) which shows how to extract other form fields and do multiple requests.  See also ([cURL -- cookies and sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10289281/curl-cookies-and-sessions/10289358#10289358)) and ([PHP Curl - Cookies problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522149/php-curl-cookies-problem/7532730#7532730))

Hope that helps, comment back with issues/questions.