# Access Denied for CURL Post

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to login to Walmart using CURL, the code works perfectly. However whenever i activate the `CURLOPT_POST` I'm getting an error Access Denied.

This is the code that I tried:

```
<?php

$user_agent       = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:24.0) Gecko/20140319 Firefox/24.0 Iceweasel/24.4.0";
$curl_crack = curl_init();
CURL_SETOPT($curl_crack,CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.walmart.com/account/login");
CURL_SETOPT($curl_crack,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$user_agent);
//CURL_SETOPT($curl_crack,CURLOPT_PROXY,"183.78.169.60:37899");
//CURL_SETOPT($curl_crack,CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE,CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);
CURL_SETOPT($curl_crack,CURLOPT_POST,True);
CURL_SETOPT($curl_crack,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"login-username=test&login-password=test");
CURL_SETOPT($curl_crack,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,True);
CURL_SETOPT($curl_crack,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,True);
CURL_SETOPT($curl_crack,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,"cookie.txt"); //Put the full path of the cookie file if you want it to write on it
CURL_SETOPT($curl_crack,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,"cookie.txt"); //Put the full path of the cookie file if you want it to write on it
CURL_SETOPT($curl_crack,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,30);  
echo $exec = curl_exec($curl_crack);



?>
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, please help me.

Comment: you probably need to turn off ssl verifying, try setting these curl options to `false`: `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFY_HOST`, `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFY_PEER`

Comment: It did not work for me

Comment: what is the purpose of this? some kind of phishing scam you're working on?

Comment: Looks like you are posting to the wrong URL.

The form should go to `https://www.walmart.com/account/api/signin` and the fields are called `username` and `password`.  They return a 403 error if the credentials are incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example.

You need to first request the home page to establish base cookies, and then post the credentials to the login page.  If a 403 error is returned, the credentials are incorrect.

```
<?php

$base_url  = 'https://www.walmart.com/';
$login_url  = 'https://www.walmart.com/account/api/signin';
$user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:24.0) Gecko/20140319 Firefox/24.0 Iceweasel/24.4.0";
$username = 'user@example.com';
$password = 'password';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $base_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$user_agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,True);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip, deflate');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,30);

//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, fopen('php://output', 'r'));

//curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_PROXY,"183.78.169.60:37899");
//curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE,CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);

$resp = curl_exec($ch);


$headers = array(
    'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest',
);

$post = array(
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password,
    'login-captcha-value' => '',
    'sensor-data' => '',
    'clearPCID' => '1',
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $login_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$exec = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);

if ($info['http_code'] != 200) {
    echo "Login failed! HTTP code {$info['http_code']}<br>\n";
    var_dump($exec);
    exit;
}

echo "Login successful!<br>\n";

// you are now logged in, use $ch to request pages as the logged in user

$url = 'https://www.walmart.com/account';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);

$account = curl_exec($ch);
```